# Seeking Postcode Boundaries for USA?

Tags: data, united-states, administrative-boundaries, zip-codes

I'm using ODL Studio to draw US zip codes, and though I can download the free database and get it to load, I can't figure out how to draw boundaries. The tutorial provided on their site explains how to do UK ones with a corresponding polygon shape file.

Is there a similar file for US zip codes?

Answer (score 2):

The [ZCTA5](ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2014/ZCTA5/)(Zip Code Tabulation Area) shapefile from the Census Bureau should have what you are looking for. [2010_ZCTA5](http://ftp2.census.gov/geo/pvs/tiger2010st) Here are single state files, although 2010 Version. Click on the State name, then the 2 digit State FIPs code, then ZCTA510.zip should be at the bottom.

Comment: Beware that GIS zipcodes may not represent true boundaries on the ground. They are a polygonized form of linear data. Read the disclaimers.

Comment: I downloaded the file; however, I get a 'Exception of type "OutOfMemoryError"' when trying to import it into ODL studio. Are there shape files by state, can I divide this one up, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You'll have to forgive me for being so dense, but I'm new to all this. When I go to that link you've provided... what do I actually download to run the shape file in ODL? There's a lot of zip files in there and I didn't see anything that looked liked zip codes specifically.

Comment: @Maksim I think those would be valuable additional instructions to edit into your answer so that it can be read standalone.

Comment: @PolyGeo would it be possible to create the tag odl-studio and add the tag to the question? I'm planning to start using gis.stackexchange.com for odl-studio Q&As but I can't until there's a tag, so I can get notifications. ODL Studio is an open source app for territory design, customer mapping, vehicle routing etc (i.e. well suited for gis.stackexchange). I would guess there'd be a few queries per week once I start directing users to gis.stackexchange...

Comment: @OpenDoorLogistics I'm not comfortable to do that without a discussion at [meta.gis.se] first.  I'm not against what you request but since this is the first question that has mentioned ODL Studio I don't feel like I have enough information to act on.  I suggest reviewing and then linking to this [earlier Meta Q&A](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3180/allowing-gis-se-to-be-support-for-particular-software-products) as a preamble to making this request there.